# What is the css to apply to a HTML select multiple to be not 3D background?

Tags: css, html

I want a select element which is multiple, to have its background an aspect plain but not 3D. What is the css for that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select{
    border:solid 1px #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it border styling (if I understand you correctly):

```
select { border: 1px solid gray; }​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PeeHaa/y5kG5/